# why can't I open my Android Studio project on XUbuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, xubuntu, android, android-studio

I am an Android developer and I use Android studio to build apps, I am also newbie in Linux and I have installed Xubuntu since 2 days, every time I try to open a project (after restaring my pc) the path of the project is not recognizable by Xubuntu and Android Studio gives me a dialog with this error message:
"The path /media/mohamed/LocalDisk/AndroidProjects/MyChatApp doesn't exist. if it is on a removable or network drive,please make sure that the drive is connected.

I have searched a lot on google and youtube to find a solution for this and I have understood that I gotta save the path of the project using the extra path command in the .bashrc file but nothing changed despite that I can see the path of the project when I run the echo $PATH command in the terminal

Comment: Why not add the drive/device to your system's *file-system table* (ie. `/etc/fstab` ) so it auto-mounts on system boot?  Personal preference; but that would be my choice rather than a script mounting it (on boot, login etc - though I've used that too for some use-cases).   It maybe I'm missing your issue; to me it reads like a removable (thus /media) mount isn't available...

Comment: and how to do that?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab  ,  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions  ,  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FSTAB  etc  (use your existing partition(s) as examples; the entry will of course vary on type of *file-system*, if network, local, always-present, occasional etc)  as a *dev* I'd assume `man fstab` at terminal would be enough for you though...

Comment: finally I am able to first understood what is the problem and then solve it, thanks man for your help I really appriciate it :)